# Unix: using sort and uniq to get a count of only individual beginnings of lines

Tags: unix

I'm trying to create a Unix script that will give me a count of unique beginnings of lines. For example, I have a `test.txt` file that has these lines in it:

```
123456
124365
123546
126453
125436
123654
124365
```

And lets say that I want a count of how many lines start with `123`.

`sort test.txt | uniq -c` gives me an output of:

```
1 123456
1 123546
1 123654
2 124365
1 125436
1 126453
```

I'm trying to figure out how to edit this so that it gives me an output similar to:

```
3 123*
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

to get all of the 3 char prefix counts you can do this

```
 cut -c1-3 test.txt | sort | uniq -c
  3 123
  2 124
  1 125
  1 126
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get a count of how many lines match a given pattern, this will do:

```
grep -c '^123' test.txt
```

The `-c` option instructs `grep(1)` to count the matches only (and suppress the usual output). The `^` in the pattern matches the beginning of a line, so this command counts how many lines in `test.txt` start with the sequence `123`.

If you really want to get an output of the form `<count> <pattern>`, you'll need something a little more complex:

```
grep -e '^123' test.txt | sed 's/^123.*/123/' | uniq -c
```

This works by first finding the lines that start with `123` (as before), then `sed(1)` removes everything after the `123` pattern in each line, and finally `uniq(1)` counts how many lines are left. The output is:

```
3 123
```

Well, it doesn't have the trailing `*` that you showed in the example, but I think it's close enough.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a problem that your data set doesn't test for. If you have a number that has 123 somewhere else in the string, in the middle or at the end.  So lets say we add `9912399` and `9999123` to the file.

You don't need to sort in this case, you just need to filter and count lines.

```
cat test.txt | grep 123
```

This will result in the following output:

```
123456
123546
123654
9912399
9999123
```

This is wrong obviously, were catching any instances of `123`. In order to make sure we are checking for `123` only when its at the beginning of the string we need to add the `^` character to the grep argument.

```
cat test.txt | grep ^123
```

Now we get the following.

```
123456
123546
123654
```

Now we just need to count lines which we can do by piping this out to the `wc` command, and pass `-l` to let it know to count lines instead of characters.

```
cat test.txt | grep ^123 | wc -l
```

Result is:

```
   3
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat test.txt | cut -c -3 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn`